# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is not to work

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void)cameraAndPhotoAlbums{
    self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Photo album",@"camera", nil];

    [self.actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if(buttonIndex==1) {
        UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(id)picker{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But at the time of photo album selected photos will only perform the cancel but finish don't perform, tried this item anywhere to write all can't, I again open a project can go agent, a great god save stunned me..

Comment: did you set the image picker controller delegate?

Comment: please explain the question little more

Comment: show some additional code

Comment: UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        //    imagePicker
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Forgive me for the first time to use stackoverflow

Comment: @paris - can you show your full class code

Comment: - (void)cameraAndPhotoAlbums{
    self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"选取图片类型" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"取消" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"相册",@"相机", nil];
    
    [self.actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

Comment: @paris please do not post code in comments. [Edit] your question with all relevant details.

Comment: I have put the code on my own answer,Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample code for you to study:

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImagePickerController * imagePicker;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)setImageToImageView:(UIButton *)sender;


@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSLog(@"%@",NSHomeDirectory());

    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Image Picker Delegate

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
    NSLog(@"Image picked");


    self.imageView.image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary)
    {
        NSData * data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 0.5);

        NSString * path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.JPEG"];
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:true];

    }
    else
    {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], nil, nil, nil);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)setImageToImageView:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.tag == 101)
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    else
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:true completion:nil];

}
@end
```

> This code works, tested it on a device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but I want to ask that “didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo" is not work

Comment: For that to work, your ViewController should conform/adopt the protocol `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. Then in your ViewController, provide the implementation for that method. Also, set the `delegate` of the imagePicker as the ViewController, i.e `self`

Comment: yes,delegate has been,camera can work，but Photo album not work

Comment: Your comment is unclear, are you unable to pick photos from photo album or the photos aren't being saved in your photo album? In either case, delete the app from your phone and install again. You will be asked for permissions, once again. Please approve them. My guess is you might have missed out on granting permissions (manually, when the app is installed/launched for the first time)